# Forwarding Meeting Invite From Outlook Mobile App

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I am trying to figure out who receives a notification when I forward a meeting invitation from the outlook mobile app and I am not the organizer. Essentially I forwarded the meeting to two participants and then included a message (which I would not want anyone else to see) . Would the organizer / rest of participants be able to see that message or that I forwarded it? After sending the forward, it’s not showing up in my sent mail so I am not able to track it. Any insights would be very helpful, thank you!

Comment: Why don't you just ask the other participants and organiser?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when you forward a meeting , Organizer will receive an email about the forwarding. But other attendees in this meeting will not get a notification.